# %27%27 in a href (javascript)

Tags: javascript

**The issue:**

```
 <a href=profile.php?u='"+id1+"'>
```

is outputting:

```
http://www.url.com/profile.php?%27%theidwilldisplayasintendedhere%27%
```

Any help would be appreciated. I haven't a clue why it would add the prefix and suffix %27% to my url or how to remove it.

**Full Code - Javascript:**

```
 <script>


function update() {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'verification.php', //php          
    data: "", //the data "caller=name1&&callee=name2"
    dataType: 'json', //data format   
    success: function (data) {
        //on receive of reply
    var id1 = data[8];           //get id1
    var id2 = data[9];           //get id2

    $('#verification').html("(<font color='"+color1+"'><b><a href=profile.php?u='"+id1+"'>"+name1+"</a></b></font>)");     //output to html
    }
    });
}

$(document).ready(update); // Call on page load
//                ^^^^^^


setInterval(update, 60000); //every 60 secs
//          ^^^^^^



</script>
```

Comment: [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) or php's [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the single apostrophes (') you put in there. Thats how they are encoded in an URL. See http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

In order to fix that, just don't put them in the URL in the first place. So: `" + id + "` instead of `'" + id + "'`.

Answer (score 1):

i guess your error leading part should look more like e.g.:

```
var myLink = '<a href="profile.php?u='+id1+'">';
```

when its in the js. Otherwise you cant use the  `+id1+` at all!